# An object attribut is undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
    name:'ian',
    getName(){
        console.log(`inside:${this.name}`)
    }
}

obj.getName()
obj.getName.call({name:'oliver'})
var fn = obj.getName.call({name:'sullivan'})
```

console.log is ian olive and sullivan,but i don't get it ,why?i didn't console fn ,why it can be output 'sullivan'?and if i do this:

```
var obj = {
    name:'ian',
    getName(){
        console.log(`inside:${this.name}`)
    }
}

obj.getName()
obj.getName.call({name:'oliver'})
var fn = obj.getName.call({name:'sullivan'})
console.log(fn)
```

it will be console ian oliver sullivan and [**undefined**]
why??need help :) please

Comment: `undefined` is the `console.log`'s return value.

Comment: Your `.getName()` function does not return anything, so the default value of the function call is `undefined`.

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The first point, is why does it log? Is because you do a console.log inside your getName function.

The second point why it returns undefined. Is because your function does not return a value. Maybe you try to do the following:

```
var obj = {
    name:'ian',
    getName(){
         return this.name;
    }
}
console.log(obj.getName());
console.log(obj.getName.call({name:'oliver'}));
var fn = obj.getName.call({name:'sullivan'})
console.log(fn)
```

Note: If you run this code in the console. you get a undefined at the end, because I don't give back a variable or value to the console.

Answer (score 0):

> console.log is ian olive and sullivan,but i don't get it ,why?i didn't console fn ,why it can be output 'sullivan'?and if i do this:

The function `call` calls the function `getName` which execute a `console.log`

```
getName(){
   console.log(`inside:${this.name}`)
}  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> and if i do this:

The function `getName()` doesn't return any value, so, by default will return `undefined`.